# Generating project in Interactive mode Taking lot of time

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

```
I run the Maven the command *mvn archetype:generate* in command Prompt
It shows
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom >>>
 [INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom <<<
 [INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
 [INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
```

I am using Maven 3.0.5 version
It is taking lot of time about 30 minutes to generate sample projects from the repository..

I dont know why it takes such a long time

Comment: Assuming you already have the archetype locally, does `--offline` (`-o`) work better?

Comment: 2022, good connection and it still takes a very long time to load. Why is it trying to "download the world"? Very bad idea IMHO. Use convention over configuration, not "all options of the world". Maven is getting obsolete for that, it seems like a design bug.

Answer (score 13):

After typing `mvn archetype:generate` maven scans remote repositories for all available archetypes so in case you connection is low it can take a long time.

I've made an experiment. I've occupied the internet channel (by downloading a torrent file) and run the command - and it seemed as it is hanging. But as soon as I paused the download maven listed out 858 available archetypes.

If you know for sure the spelling of the archetypeArtifactId you can use parameter `-DinteractiveMode=false` ([official page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)).

Example:


`mvn archetype:generate

-DgroupId=my.groupid 

-DartifactId=my-artifactId

-DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-artifactId 

-DinteractiveMode=false`

Comment: 2022, good connection and it still takes a very long time to load. Why is it trying to "download the world"? Very bad idea IMHO. Use convention over configuration, not "all options of the world". Maven is getting obsolete for that, it seems like a design bug.

Comment: @ceklock maven has a local read through cache for all dependencies. What do you mean "download the world" in this context?

Comment: If this cache is not updated it will download a lot of stuff. Specially in this case, I don't know what it is dowing behind the scene, but the displayed list in interactive mode is insanely big.

Answer (score 9):

For the users trying to build using their local archetypes, an alternate way would be to just append `-DarchetypeCatalog=local` after your command.

This should look like

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

to tell maven just looking type catalog from local instead of remote.

Comment: hey! thanks a lot for answer - it worked. aside: i tried without the Catalog=local option, but rather with `--offline` but that didn't work and it still consumed the connection. so, can you throw some light on why it's still downloading stuff despite the `--offline` flag?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal experience,

---

It depends on the speed/bandwidth of your internet connection.
You can try closing the other applications which are hogging the bandwidth.

If you are a windows user then:

To check what other applications are hogging your internet connectivity, execute the following command in command prompt:

> "netstat -a -n -o"

It will give you the list of processes which are using you connection.

Try to terminate other non essential(other than system processes and maven process) processes through task manager. It will resolve the issue.