# Generation of the project from Maven archetype hangs

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, maven-archetype

I create the folder for the project as `D:\Java\games>cd prometheus2graphana` and call for the project generation from the archetype like that:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.4

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) > generate-sources @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) < generate-sources @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Generating project in Interactive mode
```

But it hangs on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of searching it seems it is only related to a slow or slowed internet connection.

You can use `-DinteractiveMode=false` to generate the project in batch mode

Source : [Generating project in Interactive mode Taking lot of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524148/generating-project-in-interactive-mode-taking-lot-of-time)